# Eclipse does not display my project files on project explorer

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-5

When I double click on any project (go into) in `project explorer` it won't open, to display my project content, this problem happened after installing `glassfish tools` on `eclipse` for the server.
I wanted to know where i can find out what the error is that causing me the strange behavior.

**Before I double click on my project:**

[image]

**After I double click on my project :**

[image]

my project is not empty !!

before installing `glassfish` i had `jboss tools 4.0` and `spring tools 4`, when everything works fine but when i added `glassfish` i got this error (that I show the top) i tried to reset `eclipse` and install `glassfish tools` at the beginning without the other two to see will it give me another error, it worked **without error** but when I try to install `spring tools 4`  it gives me this error

[image]

Comment: Are the contents visible in the Navigator or Package Explorer views?

Comment: Check the Eclipse error log for any errors which seem to be related.  Also look at the project properties and determine the "Resource Location".  Inspect that location for a ".project" file and inspect the contents. These are all potential clue sources.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers before installing glassfish i had jboss tools 4.0 and spring tools 4, when everything works fine but when i added glassfish i got this error i tried to reset eclipse and install glassfish tools at the beginning without the other two to see will it give me another error, it worked without error but when I try to install spring tools 4 it gives me this error `Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable`